# Gitlab, merge: как УВИДЕТЬ конфликты?

Tags: git, gitlab

К меня гитлaб ругается на конфликты.

При этом он мне их не показывает, то есть в моём MR висит примерно такая табличка:

[image: конфликт-1]

Если переключиться на вкладку "Changes" в MR, то будет написано что то вроде такого:

[image: конфликт-2]

При нажатии на кнопку Merge Locally у меня не происходит ничего.

Как бы мне заставить Gitlab всё таки показать мне, в каких именно местах возникают конфликты?

Как обычно разрешаются такие ситуации?

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Уточните, какую версию gitlab используете. Попробуйте добавить к url /conflicts

Comment: @alexsteeel  - спасибо, версия - GitLab Community Edition 14.1.2 , а совет приводит к тому, что мне показывается экран с надписью "The merge conflicts for this merge request cannot be resolved through GitLab. Please try to resolve them locally." Но всё равно - прикольная фича!

Comment: Раньше была такая [проблема](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/47954), что только владелец репозитория видел кнопку "Resolve Conflicts", а создателю merge-request она была недоступна. А вы знаете, в каком файле расхождения? В [документации](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/conflicts.html#conflicts-you-can-resolve-in-the-user-interface) написано, что нет возможности поправить конфликты через UI для двоичных файлов, файлов больше 200 КБ, файлов не в UTF-8 или если у файла изменился путь.

Comment: И еще вопрос: есть ли доступ на запись в master? Нужно посмотреть protected branches в настройках репозитория и проверить для каких ролей для ветки master выставлено Allowed to merge и какая роль у вашей учетной записи.

Comment: @alexsteeel - большое спасибо за подсказки, похоже, что это был какой то глюк UI гитлаба. При просмотре через UI он показывал конфликт, а локально - нет.

Answer (score 2):

Никак нельзя сделать. Нужно локально вытянуть ветку и втянуть в нее изменения из мастера, порешать конфликты и запушить назад.

Comment: Это можно сделать средствами встроенного резрешателя конфликтов: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/conflicts.html

Comment: Читайте лучше вопрос. "Решатель конфликтов" не всегда доступен иногда требуется решать их локально. В этом и есть проблема пользователя.